# Issues in IIS Manager

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-express, iis-10

I am using IIS Manager in window 10,
I need to host my ASP .NET web Form project in iis and access from other devices in same network.

i add new website and provide physical path.
the ip access from the computer but cannot able to access from other device in same network.

It Shows:
While Authentication file.
The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify that \$ has Read access to the physical path. Then test these settings again.

Comment: Learn your site bindings first https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is IIS warning when you click test in the binding window.

By default, IIS will use identity to access the protected files.With psasthrough
authentication like impersonation, IIS will attempt to use the actual identity of the user when accessing protected resources.

If user doesn't auth, it will use application pool identity to access the resources.

In my opinion, it is just a warning not a error.